# How can I prevent my code from hanging up in while-loop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

I am creating an "AI" for a tic tac toe game in winforms, but the code is hanging up, when the AI tries to play in a randomly selected free field (in this case a corner). The status of the fields is stored in a 3*3 array, whose values are set to true for every field. Cause of the buttons being simulated by the AI with numbers from 1 to 9, I needed a pretty strange while-query to translate the following:
button 1 for field 0, 0 -
button 2 for field 0, 1 -
button 3 for field 0, 2 -
button 4 for field 1, 0
...
If the randomly selected button of the AI was not played yet, it should play this button, otherwise it should choose a different one. I am also giving the method a position-string with, which influences the position, on which should be played.

```
        public void RandomField(PlayArea playArea, String position)
        {
            int randomNumber;
            int randomX;
            int randomY;
            do
            {
                randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 5);
                switch (position)
                {
                    case "corner":
                        switch (randomNumber)
                        {
                            case 1: randomNumber = 1; break;
                            case 2: randomNumber = 3; break;
                            case 3: randomNumber = 7; break;
                            case 4: randomNumber = 9; break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "edge":
                        switch (randomNumber)
                        {
                            case 1: randomNumber = 2; break;
                            case 2: randomNumber = 4; break;
                            case 3: randomNumber = 6; break;
                            case 4: randomNumber = 8; break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "center":
                        randomNumber = 5;
                        break;
                }
                randomX = (randomNumber - 1) / 3 - ((randomNumber - 1) % 3) / 3;
                randomY = (randomNumber - 1) % 3;
            } while (Program.currentPlayer.storage[randomX, randomY] == false && Program.enemyPlayer.storage[randomX, randomY] == false);
            playArea.SimulateButtonClick(randomNumber);
        }
```

Comment: _loop invariants_

Comment: If you call the function with "corner" is it guaranteed that at least one corner has not been played? If not then the function could get stuck in the while loop trying each of the corners, which have all been played.

Comment: If you are using Visual studio it has a breakpoint counter functionality. Set a breakpoint and ask VS to stop at a number if iteration. You can then inspect the values and maybe find a clue.

Comment: Just before the end of the while loop, I would create a series of variables that break up the final expression so that the final expression can use those variables and be simplified.  I.e. `int randomX = (randomNumber - 1) / 3 - ((randomNumber - 1) % 3) / 3` , `var playerPosition = Player.storage[randomX ,randomY]`, etc., then the while loop can be `while(playerPosition == false && enemyPosition == false)`.  Having these intermediate variables will make the code more readable and also easier to debug since you can inspect those values while stepping through. Variable names self document code.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to build the list of possible positions, shuffle it, then iterate over them and see if one is available. This way you can't end up in an endless loop; if you get to the end of the shuffled list and no spot has been taken then you know that either those spots are taken and/or you need to rethink your AI algorithm...

Comment: @gunnerone Yes, that is guaranteed, nevertheless thank you!

Comment: @AaronLS Thank you for this idea. As you can see in the edited version of my comment, I have changed some part of my code, but how would "var playerPosition = Player.storage[randomX ,randomY]" work? I need an object of the Player-class...

Comment: A simple tic-tac-toe and two separate storages? The `Program.currentPlayer.storage` and `Program.enemyPlayer.storage`?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Thank you for your suggestion, but I do not know how to realize your idea in code.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes, I thought it would be good, if I am storing the played fields for each player in their player-class, so i do not need a new storage-class. :/